# Schema validation using TypenameHandling.All and List<T>

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

i have a problem using the Newtonsoft.Json.Schema NuGet (version 3.0.11) with my Settings-Editor application. The GUI receives a list of settingsfiles (serialized as json) and json schemas for each type of settingsfile. The user can now edit the settingsfiles which are then validated against the schema for the respective file.

I (de-)serialize all my applicationspecific settings using `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All` because there could be inherited types located within the specific settingsfile.

I generate the JSON schema on my settings class using NewtonSoft.Json.Schema like this:

```
new JSchemaGenerator().Generate(setting.GetType())
```

When i am trying to validate a live-edited string against the previously generated schema, i get the following ValidationError on the line of the `ListOfItems`-property:

> Invalid type. Expected Array, Null but got Object.

The JSON of the serialized List looks like that:

```
{
  ...
  "ListOfItems": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MySubSettingsClass, MyAssembly]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "MySubSettingsClass, MyAssembly",
        ...
      }]
  }
}
```

The Schema looks like that:

```
    "ListOfItems": {
      "type": [
        "array",
        "null"
      ],
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/MySubSettingsClass"
      }
    },
```

Somehow, the schema validation is not able to interprete the list-type as an array.

I already tried replacing my list with an array of these sub-settings, but that gives me the same error:

```
{
  "$type": "MySettingsClass, MyAssembly",
  "ListOfItems": {
    "$type": "MySubSettingsClass[], MyAssembly",
    "$values": [
     {
       ...
     }
  }
}
```

Can i solve that problem by using some kind of attributes above my list-property?

Comment: Those two approaches are most likely not compatible in the sense that you can coax Json.Net's type handling to emit the format you need. You likely have to construct DTO's that match the format you require and transform from your in-memory objects to the DTO's before serializing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually those settingsfiles are DTO's in my context already (also used for another kind of serialization) and i would prefer some other way around it. I keep looking, thanks!